# An error occurred due to the transfer of data from the client side to the server

Tags: php, laravel

**register.blade.php**

```
    <script>
            $(".btn-submit").on('click', function() {
                var form = $('.myForm');
                var formData = form.serialize();

                console.log(formData);

                if(formData == '' || formData == null){
                    console.log(formData);
                    alert('Null 입니다.');
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/register',  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    data: formData,  
                    dataType: 'json',  
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);  
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(error);  
                    }
                });              
            });   
            
        </script>
</html>
```

Data was passed to the server through the blade template provided by Laravel, but Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
An error has occurred. I'm not sure what the cause is. help.

There is no error in the visual studio code console, but when passing data to the server on the Chrome network side, a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) error occurs.

Is it correct that I coded the Ajax code properly? Please let me know if there are any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, make sure you have included the @csrf directive to generate the CSRF token. For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="/register" class="myForm">
    @csrf
    <!-- Rest of the form fields -->
</form>
```

Also, check that you have a corresponding route defined in your Laravel application to handle the POST request to /register. Check your web.php routes file.